# Powershell to C# - Get-WMIObject

Tags: c#, powershell

So here's the powershell:

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class SMS_UserApplicationRequest -Namespace root/SMS/site_sitename -
 ComputerName computername | Select-Object User, Application, RequestGUID

$app
```

It works fine, returns the info with no problem.

Running in c#:

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.Runspace = runspace;
powerShell.AddScript(script);

Collection<PSObject> results = powerShell.Invoke();

foreach (PSObject result in results)
{
    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
}

runspace.Close();
```

This shows the baseObject, which is the UserApplicationRequest, but how do I access the data in the request?  (That was the Select-Object User, Application, RequestGUID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on PowerShell V3 (System.Management.Automation.dll 3.0), don't forget that it is now sitting on the DLR.  That means that PSObject can be used via the `dynamic` keyword in C# e.g.:

```
foreach (dynamic result in results)
{
    var msg = String.Format{"User: {0}, Application: {1}, RequestGUID: {2}", 
                            result.User, result.Application, result.RequestGUID);
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!  Still pretty new to powershell and c# in general, so I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm running into a new issue on this - it works without a problem on the PC I wrote the code on, but any other PC, I get an exception thrown when I try to access one of the properties:

runtimebinderexception PSObject does not contain a definition for "PropertyName"

Any ideas what would cause this/why it would only work on the PC I wrote the code on?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get at the custom objects being created by the `Select-Object` cmdlet you can iterate over the `Properties` member:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    foreach ( var property in result.Properties )
    {
        MessageBox.Show( string.Format( "name: {0} | value: {1}", property.Name, property.Value ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried - I get: can't operate of variables of type PSObject because PSObject does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Shouldn't it be var property in result.Properties ?

Comment: @Mitul - It should! Sorry about that typo and I'll fix it up. :)

Comment: @ctd25 - Okay made a quick fix on a typo for the answer. Sorry about that. Think that should fix the problem you were seeing.